# "to have three meals a day" and "to have a meal three times a day" and "to have meals three times a day"

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

- I have three meals a day.
- I have a meal three times a day.
- I have meals three times a day.

I wonder if they all can convey the same meaning.  The first one seems to be the most common of the three, but do the other two sound weird?

I also wonders which one of the three below is better.

- Japan has participated in seven World Cups.
- Japan has participated in the World Cup seven times.
- Japan has participated in the World Cups seven times.

Answer (score 1):

*I have three meals a day* is indeed the usual expression. We give our meals different names according to the time of day (apart from *breakfast*, the names vary according to culture, but that's another story), so they are three different meals. It would be unusual to say *I have a meal three times a day*, but it would mean the same. *I have meals three times a day* could imply that you eat more than one meal at a time!

*The World Cup*, of course, can mean either the trophy being competed for, the competition as a whole, or a single year's event. Either the first or second sentence can be used, but the third sounds odd.